# Use UID for path in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, dom-events

There are a-lot of answers on Stack Overflow about how to get the uid once you do an `onCreate()` in cloud functions, but none to use the uid as a path. In my situation I want to monitor when a particular user gains a follower. I then what to alert that user that they have gained a follower.

Here is my code:

```
console.log('uid valll ' + exports.auth.uid)
exports.announceFollower = functions.database
 .ref('users/{exports.auth.uid}/followers/{followerId}')
 .onCreate(event => {
 let follower = event.data.val()

sendNotification(follower)     
})


 function sendNotification(follower){
 
 let uid = follower.val
 let payload = {
     notification: {
         title: 'New Follower',
         sound: 'default'
     }
 }
 console.log(payload)
 
 let topic = functions.database.ref('users/{exports.auth.uid}/followerTopicId')
 
 console.log('topic val' + topic)
 
 admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic.val , payload)
```

}

where it says `exports.auth.uid` I am attempting to grab to uid of the currently logged in user.

I try that using this function :

```
exports.auth = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
const tokenId = req.get('Authorization').split('Bearer ')[1];

return admin.auth().verifyIdToken(tokenId)
  .then((decoded) => res.status(200).send(decoded))
  .catch((err) => res.status(401).send(err));
 });
});
```

Yet I get the message in Firebase cloud func console :

```
uid valll undefined
```

After reviewing the documentation here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

It still is unclear. What is the appropriate way to access the uid of a currently logged in user **For path usage**?